# Run workflow on some pull request type that are only in a certain branch

Tags: yaml, continuous-integration, github-actions

im trying to run a workflow only on certains pull request types that are coming from a specific branch pattern.

So far I have this:

```yaml
name:  Create preview
on:
  pull_request:
    types: [labeled, opened, synchronize]
    branches:
      - 'feature/**'
```

But it is not working. As soon as I remove the branches filter, it works fines, any idea what I am doing wrong ?. I also tried to change the order between pull request and branches, but no luck so far.

There is some examples here, but not with the types filter referenced on the same moment: https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#example-including-branches

Otherwise, I guess I will have to check with an if condition that the branch match that pattern, but I wanted to have a cleaner version.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The `branches` attribute on the `pull_request` trigger specifies the `base` branch, which is the branch you are trying to merge into.

Reading your question, it looks like you want to filter on the `head` branch name, which can be achieved by adding an `if` condition to the job or step:

```yaml
if:  startsWith(github.head_ref, 'releases/')
```

This is documented under [Running your workflow based on the head or base branch of a pull request](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/events-that-trigger-workflows#running-your-workflow-based-on-the-head-or-base-branch-of-a-pull-request) in the GitHub Actions docs.

Comment: Thanks for your answer ! However, i mentioned already that I could do with an if condition like you mentioned, I was more looking for a way to do it directly within the *on:* part